# How to get an ILogger from an Activity Function?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I am using Durable Azure Function in a prototype for a future project.

Basically, I have a Client Azure Function triggered by an HTTP `POST` request that starts the Orchestrator. Then, the Orchestrator decides to trigger an Activity. Nothing complicated.

Here is a sample of what I am doing:

```
[FunctionName("ClientFunction")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> OnHttpTriggerAsync([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
            HttpRequestMessage request, [OrchestrationClient] DurableOrchestrationClient starter, ILogger logger)
{
    // Triggers the orchestrator.
    string instanceId = await starter.StartNewAsync("OrchestratorFunction", null);

    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}


[FunctionName("OrchestratorFunction")]
public static async Task DoOrchestrationThingsAsync([OrchestrationTrigger] DurableOrchestrationContext context, ILogger logger)
{
    // Triggers some serious activity.
    await context.CallActivityAsync("ActivityFunction", null);
}

[FunctionName("ActivityFunction")]
public static Task DoAnAwesomeActivity([ActivityTrigger] DurableActivityContext context)
{
    // Short & Sweet activity...
    // Wait... Where's my logger?
}
```

Both the Orchestrator and the Client Functions are being given an `ILogger` but not the Activity Function; as [stated](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2018/09/05/introduction-to-azure-durable-functions/) in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-types-features-overview#activity-functions) (either a specific parameter or the `DurableActivityContext` instance), the Activity function only gets one parameter. And I am not under the impression that the static class in which these methods are declared could keep a reference on that `ILogger`.

I understand that the Activity Function should perform one small job but I would be more comfortable if I was able to log that the activity was called with the appropriate values if something goes wrong (and it will :) ).

**Question**

How can the Activity access the `ILogger`?

Comment: What goes wrong if you put `ILogger` in the method signature of Activity Function?  There should be no restriction on using ILogger in Activity and I didn't see any error on my side either.

Comment: I did not test it because of this specific [comment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings#passing-multiple-parameters): "It is not possible to pass multiple parameters to an activity function directly." I assumed it was either my custom parameter or the DurableActivityContext ... Will try it as soon as I get back to work! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is not possible to pass multiple parameters to an activity function directly. The recommendation in this case is to pass in an array of objects or to use ValueTuples objects in .NET.

This [restriction](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-bindings#passing-multiple-parameters) you are concerned about is talking about the parameters we pass from Orchestrator to Activity Function. It doesn't mean we could only use one parameter in Activity method signature. Feel free to add `ILogger` there and complete your job as needed.

Comment: Just want to add that it might be not so obvious, but when ILogger is added to activity function method, it is getting injected there by IoC. And that is a bit confusing part - but it works.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. The ILogger is null. Any way to see a working example?